# capybara webkit-driver reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, capybara-webkit

Having a bit of an oddity with some capybara webkit-driver (`:js => true`) tests.

Tests run fine when they run on their own, but somehow in sequence, they fail.

For example, I have a request test that looks something like

```
describe "A", :js => true do
  # tests here run fine
end

describe "B", :js => true do
  # tests here fail
end
```

When I split `describe B` section into its own file, and run it using `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/b_spec.rb` however - tests run fine and pass.

Debugging this, it looks like when both sections are in the same file, somehow the webkit driver loads a 'dirty' browser session. Trying things like `page.driver.reset!` or `Capybara.reset_sessions!` or `Capybara.reset!` doesn't seem to have any effect...

When using spectator/spork this isn't a problem, since I can split the tests into different files and run them independently, but when running the full suite of tests using `bundle exec rspec` - these tests fail...

**How can I reset the webkit driver / session properly between tests?** Or I am chasing the wrong problem?

p.s. These tests are not hitting the database or altering state in any particular way, so I'm pretty sure it's some driver related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime it helps just writing the question for the solution to pop up.

The key for me was:

> These tests are not hitting the database or altering state in any particular way, so I'm pretty sure it's some driver related problem.

Turns out there *was* a state-change. In my particular case, setting `OmniAuth` into `test_mode`, which required setting it back to `false` after the previous test was running...